# Predicting future values based multiple past measurements

Tags: regression, time-series, panel-data

I feel certain this has been covered somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.
Below is a simplified example.

Imagine that you have yearly height data for a group of children, starting at birth and through age 21 (22 data points per child).

Given a new child age 13, with height history from birth, you want to predict this child's height at age 21.

What sort of model is appropriate for this? I've looked at several, and nothing seems to be appropriate.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if there is a named tool for this problem, but I would just regression of height at 21 with heights at ages 0-13 as predictors (plus all available covariates, mainly sex).

Comment: Is it out of the question to have 14 predictors and use them in this fashion? I would have assumed that would be a misuse of regression, but I'm only basing that on not having seen any examples of it in searching for how to model this problem.

Comment: Using 14 predictors is not a problem if you have a large sample. If your sample is not large, then you will need to do variable selection or use an equivalent tool.